# footer background color does not extend

Tags: html, css

I have to do a simple clone of google.com using html and Css.  The website is supposed to be pretty basic and the search bar or any of the links do not have to do anything.

Here is the git: https://github.com/orangespire/google-homepage

1. The footer background color does not extend across the whole page.
2. The footer links are supposed to be on each side, but they are all aligned left.
3. The top bar links do not work for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not make us do all the work. Set up an example somewhere (JSBin for example).

Comment: Start with a basic HTML tutorial, then move on to your project.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen  ah... thanks for the pointer.  I am really new to this stuff, so just copy/paste in the bin?  Then copy the url in my browser?

Comment: @SquareCat  I did the whole codeacademy css/html tutorial.  I think this is more of a css problem though.

Answer (score 1):

To your bottombar add `left` and `right`. This takes care of 1. and 2.

```
#bottombar {
    ...
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

To your #googlelogo, add `float`. This takes care of 3. (note there are other better ways to take care of this, but this seems the simplest)

```
#googlelogo {
    float: left;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> The footer background color does not extend across the whole page.

There are two reasons for that. You haven't set the margin/padding for the body element, so it has its default margin/padding, which causes a distance between the edge and the content. As some browers uses margin and some padding, you should set both of them:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The other reason is that absolutely positioned elements doesn't fill up the width of the parent. As you take them out of the flow the size is determined by its content, it's only as wide as it needs to be to hold the content. You can add this to your `#bottombar` rule to make it take up the full width:

```
width: 100%;
```

> The footer links are supposed to be on each side, but they are all
>   aligned left.

They are actually aligned on each side, but you don't see that. As the bottom bar is only as large as its content require, there is no extra space to do the alignment in. By giving the bottom bar a width, you will see that the links are aligned correctly.

> The top bar links do not work for some reason.

That's because you have placed the `#googlelogo` element so that it covers the links. You can start by adding this to the rule for the element, so that it is placed below the floating top bar:

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense about the padding and margin.  Thanks for your help.